# Triangles with equal area in a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

These are two questions that have come up to my mind. I do not want to make 2 different questions, because the second one is quite short and might be very simple to answer.

**1)** $ABCD$ is a quadrilateral and $E$ is the intersection between diagonals $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BD}$. Assume that $\triangle BEC$ and $\triangle AED$ have the same area. Then do $\triangle ABE$ and $\triangle CED$ have the same area?

What I did was to use the formula for the area of a triangle with sides $\overline{a}$, $\overline{b}$, and $\overline{c}$, and $\angle A$ opposite to $\overline{a}$:

$$\text{Area} = \frac{bc \sin (A)}{2}$$

With that I can't get that $BE \cdot EC = AE \cdot ED$. Then, with that you can show that $\overline{AB} || \overline{CD}$ and then you can show that $[\triangle ABE] = [\triangle CED]$. Is there any simpler way to get this conclusion?

Comment: One question at a time please, especially since the problems are unrelated.

Comment: 1) is not true, consider trapezoid $ABCD$

Comment: _isosceles_ trapezoid

Comment: @quasi: doesn't have to be isosceles

Comment: @Vasya: True, but if it's isosceles, the counterexample is immediately obvious. In any case, you posted a nice answer.

Comment: Then what if it isn´t an isosceles trapezoid?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Claim 1) is not true. Consider trapezoid. 
$A_{\triangle{ABC}}=A_{\triangle{BCD}}$ (triangles with the same base between parallel lines). 
Hence, $A_{\triangle{ABE}}=A_{\triangle{CDE}}$ but $A_{\triangle{BCE}} \ne A_{\triangle{AED}}$

Answer (score 0):

2) it is true because

every edge of the regular polygon is 
a chord of its circumcircle and a tangent to its incircle with the point of tangency being its midpoint.